# Не с краткими прилагательными

Tags: частица-не

Как здесь пишется краткое прилагательное "не оптимально", слитно или раздельно?

Ранее предлагаемое решение вряд ли неоптимально и требует дальнейшего рассмотрения.

Answer (score 1):

Само предложение составлено очень странно. Обычно мы говорим "вряд ли оптимально" (вряд ли удачно, вряд ли хорошо и т.п.), но употреблять "вряд ли" с "НЕ"?! Так не говорят, так не по-русски. Да еще и "требует дальнейшего рассмотрения". Требует или вряд ли требует?

Answer (score 1):

Правильно:

Ранее предлагаемое решение вряд ли не оптимально и требует дальнейшего рассмотрения.

ПОЯСНЕНИЕ

Отрицательная частица НЕ может  входить в  состав частиц  ЕДВА ЛИ НЕ, ЧУТЬ ЛИ НЕ и пишется в этом случае обычно раздельно:  Он  едва ли не первый ученик в школе. Это чуть ли не первый случай.

Маленьким мальчиком я взял его к себе , вырастил его, поучил немного, и он теперь оказывается одним из полезнейших для меня людей и вряд ли не единственный в мире человек, искренно привязанный ко мне…

Примечание

Но смысл предложения не очень ясен. Мне кажется, что здесь возможны два варианта:

(1) Ранее предлагаемое решение вряд ли оптимально и требует дальнейшего рассмотрения.

(2) Ранее предлагаемое решение вряд ли не оптимально и не требует дальнейшего рассмотрения.

Comment: Vera, ключевые слова в Вашем ответе --  "Но смысл предложения не очень ясен".

А коли СМЫСЛ НЕ ЯСЕН, то разве можно говорить, что это предложение написано ПРАВИЛЬНО? (См.  Ваше: "Правильно:
Ранее предлагаемое решение вряд ли не оптимально и требует дальнейшего рассмотрения.")

Answer (score 0):

Оптимальное решение в условном смысле уникально: это выявленный по ряду критериев компромисс, напр. между противоречивыми численными характеристиками. Поэтому противоположность оптимальности (всё остальное) неестественно трактовать как самостоятельное свойство, выражая его отдельным прилагательным с отрицательной приставкой. Можно только усмотреть отсутствие (отрицание) свойства "оптимальности", отсюда написание прилагательного (краткого или полного) с отдельной частицей "не" - как и "не уникально".

P.S. Поначалу не обратил внимания на само предложение (рассматривал только слитность-раздельность). Его можно перефразировать так:

Не исключено, что предлагавшееся ранее решение оптимально, оно заслуживает дальнейшего рассмотрения.

(С сохранением отрицания.

Ранее предлагавшееся решение вряд ли можно назвать "не оптимальным": этот вопрос требует дальнейшего рассмотрения. )

Answer (score 0):

**ВАРИАНТЫ:**

*Вряд ли правильно утверждение, что...*

*Нет никаких оснований утверждать, что...*

*Необоснованно утверждение, что...*

*Преждевременно утверждать, что...*

*...предложенное ранее решение не оптимально. К рассмотрению этого решения стоит вернуться.*

**Или:**

*Ранее предлагавшееся решение может оказаться и оптимальным. Его стоит рассмотреть повнимательнее.*

**Или варианты** **Alex_ander**'а:

*Не исключено, что предлагавшееся ранее решение оптимально, оно заслуживает дальнейшего рассмотрения.*

*Ранее предлагавшееся решение вряд ли можно назвать "не оптимальным": этот вопрос требует дальнейшего рассмотрения.*